# Can we trigger firebase cloud functions when we create a collection (not "document")?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to achieve a scenario where firebase triggers only once when a collection is created and not every time that a document is added to the collection. Let's say I want it to trigger only for the first document added to the collection and not for every other document added to the same collection. How can that be done? Please help !!!

Comment: A solution for this would really be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such trigger for Cloud Functions.  Your trigger path must specify exactly one document, or use wildcards to specify a path that could possibly match many documents.

If you want to know what a collection contains its first document, you will have to either:

1. Maintain a count of documents in that collection (perhaps in yet another document in another collection), and trigger of the change of that value when it goes from 0 to 1.
2. Query **all** of the documents in the collection where a document was just created in order to figure out if it was the first one.

Both of these requires a fair amount of extra code - very much not trivial to implement correctly for arbitrary collections.  They could also run into problems under heavy load.  If these options won't work for you, I suggest figuring out another way to get you function to trigger at the right time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted to reduce the load on the functions so that they don't trigger after the first document is created. Looks like trying to achieve this would result in more load than the present condition. Hence, I think that I will leave it as is.

Answer (score -1):

While It's not possible to do directly. You can check if collection contains any elements, and if it does it means that it exists.

```
const result =await firestore.collection("collection").limit(1).get()
if(result.size){
  // Collection exists
}
```